# #[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, azure, authentication

So, here what I am doing
from the below link:
https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#from-sources

I am trying to follow all the steps mention in the blog for the installation of `django_microsoft_auth`.

```
Step-1 i.e. "pip install django_microsoft_auth" # is working
Step-2 i.e. "git clone git://github.com/AngellusMortis/django_microsoft_auth" # is also working
Step-3 i.e. "python setup.py install" # is giving me the below error.
```

> C:\Users\vtinkhed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe:
>   can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I don't know how to help. Could anybody help me out here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start setup.py from the folder where it is located.

Use `cd` to get to that folder, then run `python setup.py install`

Comment: I tried as per your guidance, but it is still going in C:\Users\vtinkhed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 and still giving me the same error.

Comment: Open the folder with setup.py in windows explorer. When holding Shift, right click on an empty space and select 'Open PowerShell window here'. Then enter `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue. My problem was that my script had a space in in. ' hello.py' instead of 'hello.py'. After renaming it worked well.